# How to safely reconfigure networking on a hosted server?

Tags: networking, 16.04, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have Ubuntu Xenial installed on a server hosted in a data centre. I have SSH access only - no iLO card. Server has a single ethernet connection.

I am setting this up as a KVM hypervisor. For networking, I believe I should use the Public Bridge method ([more info](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking)). Each guest will have a public IP address.

I have been experimenting setting up networking on a local VM which is working ok. I need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and then run `ifdown eth0; ifup br0`.

My big concern is that running this on the hosted server could lock me out. I guess I can contact support to get them to help me, but I'd rather avoid this. Is there some way I can do this with a kind of safety backup in place?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution may be have your commands run in a script in the background.  Take them down, then bring them back up if it has failed.

You would need to extend this script to move your edited eth0 script, in or out depending on the condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
ifdown eth0; ifup br0
if curl https://google.com
then
echo "Test passed."
else
ifdown br0 ; ifup eth0
fi
```

Obviously, test this in a local environment first.  You may have to sleep the script to allow for the interfaces to actually be connected with an ip.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in such a situation was to create an `at`-job  (`sudo apt install at`) that reverts my actions. This way I did not depend on the system detecting some failure.

For instance

```
$ at now +2 min
at> /sbin/ifdown br0; /sbin ifup eth0
```

you end the input with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Back in the shell you can check the at queue with `atq`, you can remove unnecessary entries with `atrm` (see `man at`).